# Where to find industrial/futuristic tilesets and graphics for maptool (for free)

Tags: battle-map, online-resources, maps

I need maptool graphic/tileset packs to make my own maps. I've been looking on RPGtools forums and other sites, but most threads are long dead and the links don't work. Furthermore, most of the assets are for fantasy sets.

Where can I find a good working library for industrial/futuristic graphic tilesets and graphics?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. Because most of the material is copyrighted, people generally have personal libraries as it is frowned on to share other people's material. However, most of the good tile designers post there stuff all over the place, so for personal use, I doubt there's any issue, but you would need to do the trolling yourself. There's a few sites that host public material, but not really in a "working library".

I used to keep a set of tiles that have caught my eye on [dunjinni](http://dunjinni.com/forums), [campaign cartographer](http://forum.profantasy.com/) and just on google image searches. I also pulled some from [filter forge](https://www.filterforge.com/filters/).

After a while though, I stopped using MT to make the map and started using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/). I just draw it out as a simple grid and then use RobA's [dungeon map maker](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=2759&page=7&p=114446&viewfull=1#post114446) script. Even though that's designed to give it a "stone effect", I found I could tweak it and use futuristic looking tiles to get a nice top down look for a building or ship. The nice thing about this script is you are largely working with the equivalent of a hand drawn map to begin with. I don't put the objects on the map, for the most part. I leave that to overlay in map tool, especially if they can be moved or destroyed.

I also used some of the [Star Wars maps](http://starwarsmaps.blogspot.com/) for source material.

If you don't mind paying for high quality material, [Future Armada](http://0-hr.com/Future_Armada/) is one of my favorite lines.